# Select PGP signature key in KMail

Tags: encryption, gnupg, signature, kmail

I have just generated a new PGP key pair with KGpg. I want to use the key for signing and encrypting mails. I have done that before without problems ... now it no longer works. Either I have made a mistake or something in Kubuntu 16.04 has changed.

The generation of the key was easy. I also could select the key in my KMail identity settings for purpose of encryption. Directly above that setting I tried to choose the same key for signing purpose but the key list in the selection dialog is completely empty.

I've tried everything possible, but I can not select a signature key. Also I can not start the certificate manager from that dialog (maybe that manager could help).

KGpg says about the key "Capabilities: signature, encryption, authentication, legalization" (hope I translated this correctly). It is an RSA/RSA key 4096/4096.

Does someone have an idea why I can select the key for encryption but not for signing in KMail's identity settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to install Kleopatra, to export the private key using KGpg and import it in Kleopatra. Afterwards I was able to select the key in KMail for signing. Doesn't make much sense but it worked that way.